# get number of selected element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have select:

```
<select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option selected>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

How Can I know number of selected element?
I use:

```
var shop_val = $("select option").eq();
```

but its return object, I want number of elements and each item's Value.

Comment: Do you mean the number (count) of selected elements? Or the index (position) of the one element that has been selected?

Comment: I was mean .index(), sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("select option:selected").index()+1 gives the number
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this

```
var shop_val = $("select option:selected").length();
```

you can do like this also

```
$("select").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
      });
  alert(str);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

1. add value attributes to the options
2. `$('select').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :selected selector to select the selected items, and then get the .length, like this:

```
var sel = $("#mySelect :selected").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
    var shop_val = $("select option:selected").index();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add value attribute as

```
<select>
   <option value=1>Option1</option>
   <option selected value=2>Option2</option>
   <option value=3>Option3</option>
</select>
```

and then use

`$('select').val();`

Comment: +1. Or maybe look at the text inside. Seems safer than depending on positions.